# Is this a shorthand for console.log?

Tags: javascript

In advanced Javascript by Kyle Simpson he says that this:

```
var foo = "bar";
```

can be evaluated like this:

```
foo;
```

And that it's just a shortcut for console.log.

But when I try it nothing shows in the console.

Why is that?

Cheers

Comment: Probably because Kyle Simpson is wrong, or something is missing from what you've posted

Comment: It isn't a "shorthand" per se. If you run that in the developer console, you will see the result `"bar"` because the statement will be evaluated and returned but that's it. Doesn't work in an actual script.

Comment: You can print like this from browser developer console not in the appside.

Comment: Doesn't print in my console?

Comment: By "evaluated" he might mean "confirmed" or "seen" like you can see what it is by calling `foo` in your terminal. That way you can find out what it is since the terminal prints out the returned value of the given input. It'll basically tell you what the things return. Here have a look at this https://i.gyazo.com/bfda0b34482f3d52f25e7c9a0daeb1af.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you type that **in the console** and press Enter, the console will show you the result of the expression, which is the value of `foo`. The console shows you the resulting value of any expression you type into it. In the console itself, there's rarely any need to type `console.log`. (In fact, if you typed `console.log(foo);` into the console and pressed Enter, you'd see the value of `foo` followed by `undefined`, because `console.log` returns `undefined`, so the console shows you that value.)

In code *not* typed into the console itself, no, `foo;` is not shorthand for `console.log(foo);`. It's just an *ExpressionStatement* sitting on its own that basically does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

In chrome var foo = "bar"; then underneath foo; doesn't print the value for some reason.

Comment: @JoeConsterdine that is strange. The only reason I can think of that happening is if the tab you're in is currently stuck in an infinite loop or something like that. If _none_ of the JS on the page works, the dev console also won't work. [Here is what happens when I run it](http://i.imgur.com/9ZlE3dm.png)

Comment: Oh my bad I get what you mean now when you say you can't run it in a script.

I was doing it via my text editor rather in the actual console.

You even put it in bold haha.

Ok cool i get ya now. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

`foo;` is not a shorthand for `console.log(foo)`.

Suppose in code, you have defined a variable `var name="mrid"` you'll have to write `console.log(name)` to print it in console. But you can directly type `name` in console and it will print it's value.